# Tailwind CSS 'group' property not working with border color

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a border color to a button inside of my main div , my code looks like this:

```html
      <div className=" group w-full flex justify-between border border-white border-solid rounded-15px px-10 items-center ">
          <button className="text-2xl flex rounded-22px border border-solid border-white py-4 px-6 my-6 items-center bg-white text-black group-hover:border-primary group-focus:border-primary transition-all ">
            rate
          </button>
          <span className="text-3xl font-bold ">{name}</span>
      </div>
```

The docs mention to add `group` to the parent and `group-hover` to the child, but it does nothing for me and the `group` property on the parent doesn't isn't highlighted by intellisense. Any idea what could be happening?

my tailwind config file is :

```
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    borderColor: ["group-hover"],
    textColor: ["responsive", "hover", "focus", "group-hover"],
  },
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      mobile: "390px",
      tablet: "744px",
      desktop: "1280px",
    },
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "0.938rem",
      screens: {
        desktop: "1864px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: { primary: "#0B1D31", warning: "#E08400", success: "#007512" },
      fontFamily: {
        roboto: ["'Roboto'", "sans-serif"],
        inter: ["''Inter'", "sans-serif"],
      },
      borderRadius: {
        "15px": "0.938rem",
        "17px": "1.063rem",
        "18px": "1.125rem",
        "22px": "1.375rem",
        "31px": "1.938rem",
        "41px": "2.563rem",
        "45px": "2.813rem",
      },
    },

    backgroundImage: {
      "primary-background": "url('/src/assets/background-image.png')",
    },
  },

  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: You're defining multiple borders, you don't need `border` or `border-solid` these are both defaults from `border-white`. 
Have you extended `primary` as a colour in `tailwindconfig`?

Comment: It might be helpful to include your `tailwind.config.js` file in your question.

Comment: I added the tailwind file

Answer (score 0):

try removing whitespace at the beginning and end of your className

Comment: that didn't fix it unfortunately

Comment: I was reading the Tailwind Css documentation but I didn't find this `border-primary` class, try using another color to see if that could be it

Comment: that's a custom color I added , I tried it with tailwind main colors and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This may just be a problem with your `primary` color. The group hover does work when using a stock Tailwind color (e.g. `blue-700`):

```html
<div className="rounded-15px group flex w-full items-center justify-between border border-solid border-white px-10">
  <button className="rounded-22px my-6 flex items-center border border-solid border-white bg-white py-4 px-6 text-2xl text-black transition-all group-hover:border-blue-700 group-focus:border-blue-700">rate</button>
  <span className="text-3xl font-bold">{name}</span>
</div>
```

You can see it working in the playground here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/yHvU4kgGpd

One possibility is that you've overwritten the default colors in your `tailwind.config.js` file. Please ensure that you are including your custom colors in the `extend` section. For example:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primary': '#243c5a'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assumed so as well but it doesn't seem like I did when I check my config file , check out my edit